# Saving Related Objects with Primary Object in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I've been reading the documentation regarding savings objects that are related to other objects, but I keep getting stuck.

Here's a simplified view of my schema:

**Class: Aircraft**

Columns: `objectId (String)`, `name (String)`

**Class: CustomValue**

Columns: `objectId (String)`, `value (String)`, `aircraft (Pointer<Aircraft>)`

When I save an aircraft, can the custom values that point to it get saved along with it automatically? Or do I have to save the custom values separately? I'm doing this in Swift, but I suspect the same principle applies regardless of the SDK.

```
var aircraft = PFObject(className: "Aircraft")
aircraft["name"] = "aaa"

var customValue1 = PFObject(className: "CustomValue")
  customValue1["value"] = "bbb"
  customValue1["aircraft"] = aircraft

var customValue2 = PFObject(className: "CustomValue")
  customValue2["value"] = "ccc"
  customValue2["aircraft"] = aircraft

aircraft.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{ () -> Void in 
  //Save aircraft, customValue1, customValue2 all together somehow?
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there. The issue is that the `CustomValue` is associated with an `Aircraft`, but the `aircraft` is not associated with the `CustomValue` objects, so saving the `aircraft` won't trigger a save of the `CustomValue` objects.

What you need to do is save all your `CustomValue` objects, and `aircraft` will be saved correctly.

So, something like...

```
PFObject.saveAllInBackground([customValue1, customValue2]) { result, error in
  // Now all three are saved together, even though aircraft wasn't explicitly saved.
}
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant! That worked, thank you! I also didn't know about `PFObject.saveAllInBackground` which is very convenient when I have a lot of objects to save. Thanks a ton!

Comment: It's also worth noting that `saveAllInBackground` can take the customValue AND aircraft objects. This is helpful because my aircraft object is required, but custom values are optional. Putting all the objects in there to be saved will make sure they all get saved once, even if no custom values are specified. :)